# Need advice on how to add links in users profile page?

Tags: links, profiles

I am working on a website where I need to have links to posts or pages that a user has added to the website. For example, a user can login to the backend of the website and they will automatically go to their profile page. In the profile page, they can see what posts and pages they have added. I want them to be able to edit their own posts or pages when they click on a link in the profile page.

I know how to add extra fields in the profile page, but I am not sure how to add links that will take them to the editor for their own posts and pages. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: If the answer was helpful to you, then consider accepting it. See »[What should I do when someone answers my question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)?« and/or »[Why is voting important](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)?«, more information about the [wordpress.se] model is available at the [help].

Answer (score 1):

WordPress has the function [`edit_post_link()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/edit_post_link) to

> Displays a link to edit the current post, if a user is logged in and allowed to edit the post.